# Vim Script to hightlight end of a tag like braces

Tags: vim, scripting

I need a Vim script to highlight end of a tag when cursor is at the beginning of the tag.

For example in html tags, when cursor is in start of tag, it should highlight the end of the tag.

The interface should be generic, so that more tags can be added

Comment: Wow, you'd think this would have been done somewhere, but I couldn't find it. On a separate note, you might find matchit useful. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39

Answer (score 3):

If you replace your html.vim file with [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075) one, you'll get the html tag matching plus some extra stuff. Or you can use [matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) which is more general purpose.

Comment: I tried html.vim first on html file but tag matching highlighting doesnt seem to work? any ideas?

Comment: You're right, I don't think these do the highlighting. However if you press % over a tag it will jump to the match. You could probably edit the script to highlight the match, but that's if you want it bad enough to do some work...