# Can Vim highlight matching HTML tags like Notepad++?

Tags: html, notepad++, vim

Vim has support for matching pairs of curly brackets, parentheses, and square brackets. This is great for editing C-style languages like PHP and JavaScript. But what about matching HTML tags?

Notepad++ has had this feature for as long as I’ve been using it. Being able to spot where blocks of HTML begin and end is very useful. What I’m looking for is something like this for Vim (see the green div tags):

[image: Example of matching HTML tags highlighting]

A bonus feature: highlighting unclosed HTML tags, like the red tag in the above screenshot.

[matchit](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) has been proposed as the next-best-thing, but it requires an extra keystroke to use its functionality. I’d like be able to see where the blocks of HTML begin and end without an extra keypress.

I’ve trawled the internet to find something like this for Vim. Apparently, I’m not the only one, according to [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154193/using-vim-as-a-html-editor) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957083/vim-script-to-hightlight-end-of-a-tag-like-braces/1960175) StackOverflow questions and a Nabble [thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-can-Vim-highlight-the-matching-tag-when-I-put-the-cursor-on-the-other-one-in-a-pair-of-tags-td1177554.html).

I’ve almost resigned myself to Vim not being able to visually match HTML tags. Is it possible for Vim to do this?

Addendum: If it is not currently possible to do this with any existing plugins, does any Vimscript wizard out there have any pointers on how to approach writing a suitable plugin?

Comment: Could you explain in what way this feature "is very useful"? I don't really need to know everything on everything at every moment. When I need to know something Vim is designed to make it **very** easy to know in very few keystrokes.

Comment: While I don't need to know everything, being able to easily know when an HTML tag ends allows me to grok the structure of the file I'm working with. I also deal with a lot of badly-written code, so sometimes I'll encounter a html tag with no closing tag, which always needs to be fixed.

Comment: @romainl I read your answer very often and I really like your point of view. But this time I have to disagree. I can consider this feature not essential but I find that this is a pretty nice question. It looks strange to mine that there isn't an easy way to get it with Vim.

Comment: @lucapette, thank you. I like the question too, actually. I've never used such a feature and I've never felt the need for it. But it's probably one of those things you can't live without once you try. I like my workflow and workspace clean and focused, free from "administrative debris" and I _think_ such a feature _might_ be superfluous. The perfect candidate for a plugin. One may try to take inspiration from matchit as a starting point, probably.

Comment: You could take a look at the matchparen plugin (`:help matchparen`). This should be distributed with Vim. It performs the highlighting for parenthesis etc. The logic used to achieve this shouldn't be too dissimilar to the logic needed to match html tags.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957083/vim-script-to-hightlight-end-of-a-tag-like-braces/1960175#1960175

Comment: I know that doesn't really answer the question, but when your code is nicely formatted (IndentGuide)[http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3361] can be usefull. It will draw a vertical line between the two divs.

Comment: @GregSexton, thanks for the link but unfortunately it is not much more than matchit with some additional html indentation rules.

Comment: @mb14, I appreciate the link; indent guides are also definitely something I'm interested in. However, it is not directly related to this question in particular (btw, you might want to check your link formatting, seems that the ']' is not formatted properly).

Comment: You could use JetBrains WebStorm (or any IDE built by them) and install the Vim plugin within their repository. Works identical to Vim. I absolutely love it.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

I had to work with some HTML today so thought I would tackle this. Added a ftplugin to vim.org that should solve your problem.

[You can get it here on vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3818).

[You can get it here on github](https://github.com/gregsexton/MatchTag).

Hope it works for you. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the functionality I'm looking for. Only two minor quibbles, if you feel like fixing them:
1. Currently, only the opposite tag is matched. Would it be possible to also match the tag that the cursor is on?
2. Currently, if a html tag has attributes, those are selected as well. Is it possible only to select the tag name, without attributes?

Comment: Good suggestions. They should both be taken care of in v1.2 up on vim.org. The matching regex is more complicated now so let me know if you find any bugs.

Comment: Not sure if you can do anything about this: one thing that I noticed was that the first tag highlight only shows up if the bottom tag is visible on the screen. Once again, thank you again very much for solving this problem!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I think I like it how it is currently but removing lines 72-75 should fix this.

Comment: I have noticed a bug : If your cursor is over an element without a closing tag (let's say <div />), it sometimes highlight the next closing tag of the same name, even if it shouldn't! However, appart from this it's really usefull.

I've noticed this bug in an XML schemas, don't know if it's present in HTML too.

Here is an example of what I'm saying : 
http://i.imgur.com/4JNQL.png

Comment: I think this problem is resolved by the latest version on github. If you still have any problems please could you raise an issue there. Thanks.

Comment: Just found this, looks good, but note that I had to add "filetype plugin on" to my ~/.vimrc to get it to turn on. If it's not working after you place the plugin in your ftplugin folder, add the above to your ~/.vimrc and you should be all set.

Comment: Brilliant work. I modified this plugin slightly to work in multiple buffers by changing "<buffer> call ..." to "*.html call ..."

Answer (score 101):

Greg's MatchTag.vim plugin is awesome, but I wanted something more. I wanted the enclosing tags to *always* be highlighted, not just when the cursor is on one of the tags.

So I wrote [MatchTagAlways](https://github.com/valloric/MatchTagAlways) which does everything that Greg's MatchTag does and also always highlights the enclosing tag, no matter where the cursor is in the code. It also works with unclosed tags and HTML templating languages like Jinja or Handlebars.

Here's a GIF showing it in action:

[image: MTA in action]

Comment: This works better than the accepted answer. But I am still unsure how to verify tags that beyond the vertical screen height. I can't move the screen past the cursor in vim and a split screen doesn't show the active tags in both windows.

Comment: last update, it's working very well with Golang *.gtpl file

Comment: Throws a bunch of errors for PHP files in latest Neovim.

Comment: instead of "highlight" the entire tag ( which is my case the color is really bad looking ) how hard it is to convert the highlight -> underline ? not familiar with VIM syntax, can you give me a suggestion ? please

Comment: FYI: I installed gVim using chocolatey on windows. It doesn't have Python support so I can't use this plugin. Unfortunate!

Answer (score -2):

I came here looking for matching html style angle brackets in Vim. This seems to work:

```
:set mps+=<:>
:help matchpairs
```

Comment: This method is not the solution, it just let '<' match to '>'