# Custom block limiters in vim

Tags: navigation, vim

How can I add custom word pairs to mark beginning and end of block in gvim, so that I can jump across using `%` (just like `{` and `}`)

I would like to jump from `functionstart` to `functionend` and viceversa.

```
functionstart

<code here>

functionend
```

Comment: `:help matchit-newlang`.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more ?

Comment: @glts I don't have that help in my version of vim. Is that from a plugin?

Comment: @Jean @FDinoff Ah right, it's a standard plugin that is included in Vim's runtime. It enhances `%` and makes it customizable. See @Nikita's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like described by others this is what you should do:

Put  `matchit.vim` in [matchit.zip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39)`/plugin/matchit.vim` in your `~/.vim/plugin` directory(`mkdir ~/.vim/plugin if it doesn't exist`) and add this line to your `~/.vimrc`. This will enable jumping across keyword pairs using <kbd>%</kbd>.

`let b:match_words = '\<functionstart\>:\<functionend\>' "Keyword pairs`

Put these two lines instead if you want to make the same keywords work for all vim buffers

```
let g:match_words = '\<functionstart\>:\<functionend\>' "Keyword pairs
autocmd BufReadPre * let b:match_words = g:match_words "Buffer specific variable
```

Comment: I feel like it would be better to use a filetype specific plugin. Do this by add `let b:match_words = '\<functionstart\>:\<functionend\>'` to `~/.vim/ftplugin/foo.vim` where `foo` is your filetype.

Comment: Is it possible to highlight both keywords if cursor is on top of any one of them ? Just like how it is done for `{` `}` ?

Comment: You will have to do something like this plugin: https://github.com/gregsexton/MatchTag The related StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168320/can-vim-highlight-matching-html-tags-like-notepad

Answer (score 1):

`:help %` suggests using either `matchpairs` (only applicable to characters) or the `matchit` plugin.

See `:help matchit-install` for installation instructions, and then `:help matchit-configure` and `:help matchit-newlang` to set up specific settings. This documentation is also available [online](http://ftp.id.vim.org/runtime/macros/matchit.txt).